# creating node of a linked list doesn't work in GLUT

Tags: c++, linked-list

consider myself as a newbie in opengl, c++, this forum, and english, so i'm sorry if i make any mistakes.

i'm trying to make a danmaku game in opengl, currently i want to make a linked list of bullets that exists on the screen.

the methods of the linked list class are:

- creating a single bullet
- drawing all the bullets + update the location/movement
- checking each bullet's age and lifespan (delete bullet if expired).

i tested it and the createBullet method is not making any new nodes.

the node format:

```
struct Bullet {
double x;
double y;
double speed;
double direction;
int birthFrame;
int lifeTime; //in frames
Bullet *next;
};
```

the method to create node:

```
void createBullet(int x, int y, int speed, int dir, int life)
{
    printf("test");
    bulletCount++;
    Bullet *temp = new Bullet;
    temp->x = x;
    temp->y = y;
    temp->speed = speed;
    temp->direction = dir;
    temp->lifeTime = life;
    temp->birthFrame = current_frame_num;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = temp;
        tail = temp;
        temp = NULL;
    } else {
        tail->next = temp;
        tail = temp;
    }
    printf("%d",bulletCount);
}
```

full code:
https://pastebin.com/Tk3pHjHp

Comment: the code at the beginning of  drawBullet() and checkBullet() is meaningless:

`Bullet *temp = new Bullet;
            temp = head;`

Initialise `temp` to `head` without introducing a memory leak

Comment: And what happens when you debug `drawBullets()`? Where does control go? How do you know nodes are not created?

Comment: Any particular reason you are creating your own linked list instead of using `std::vector` or `std::list`?